# Multiply a Datacolumn by a parameter

Tags: vb.net, datatable, operation

I have a DataColumn and I want to multiply all the rows in it by a certain value. Assuming that I have one column named *price*, the [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression) property allows me to do this in the following way:

```
MyDataColumn.Expression = "price * 0.0862"
```

But what if I do want to use a parameter? I would like to write:

```
Dim tax As Double = 0.0862
MyDataColumn.Expression = "price * tax"
```

But doing so in Visual Basic actually multiplies the column *price* with the column *tax*, which is not what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a variable like this:

```
Dim tax As Double = 0.0862
MyDataColumn.Expression = "price * " & tax
```

**Edit:**

You have to convert `tax` to a string with `InvariantCulture` first:

```
Dim tax As Double = 0.0862
MyDataColumn.Expression = "price * " & tax.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

since otherwise, `MyDataColumn.Expression` will be `price * 0,0862` instead of `price * 0.0862` and the DataColumn will complain about a bad syntax.

Comment: Hi BigYellowCactus and thanks for answering. Doing so I get a syntax error. Same thing if I declare first `Dim strExpression as String = "price * " & tax` and do `MyDataColumn.Expression = strExpression `

Comment: It's probably at runtime, and I'm wondering if it's because of how the implicit tax.ToString() has occured. I like using String.Format (or ToString with a format specifier) to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: DataTable's can complain about the syntax of the actual expression at runtime :-) It doesn't actually get evaluated by the DataTable class until then.

Comment: I already upvoted, but I'd say that was right. It's worth updating your answer with that as that is almost certainly it :-)

Comment: Hi, that was indeed the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` that was needed. Thanks!